# How to locate elements that meet a condition in one matrix to identify elements in a second matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, subset

I want to identify the positions of elements in one matrix that meet a condition to then apply those positions to another matrix and find the means of those.

```
my_vector_1<-c(1,2,1,4,1,1,7,8,)
my_matrix_1<-matrix(data=my_vector_1, nrow=3, ncol=3)

my_vector_2<-c(2,4,6,8,10,11,12,13,14)
my_matrix_2<-matrix(data=my_vector_2, nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

First locate the positions of `my_matrix_1==1` in the first matrix to find...

```
[1,1]
[2,2]
[3,1]
[3,2]
```

Then find the mean of the elements in the second matrix that are in the positions identified above...

```
7.25    #mean of 2, 10, 6, 11 in my_matrix_2
```

Comment: Use `which(my_matrix_1 == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You could subset `my_matrix_2` where `my_matrix_1` has value 1 and take `mean` of those values.

```
mean(my_matrix_2[my_matrix_1  == 1])
#[1] 7.25
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `arr.ind` to find the row/column position

```
ind <- which(my_matrix_1 == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
ind
#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   3   1
#[3,]   2   2
#[4,]   3   2


mean(my_matrix_2[ind])
#7.25
```

---

Another way to do this would be

```
mean(my_matrix_2 * NA^(my_matrix_1 != 1), na.rm = TRUE)
```